# owl carousel zoom on focused item

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I try to zoom item when its selected, but i don't know the event to do that
here my code

```
<div class="loop owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item" id="item">
          <h4>1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="item">
          <h4>2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>3</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>5</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>6</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>7</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>8</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>9</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>10</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>11</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>12</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and i already try to make event make display=none to display=block but its only work only to the first item

```js
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
    center: true,
  items: 1,
  loop: false,
 margin: 15,
 responsive: {
   800: {
  items: 7
   }
 }
 
  });
// Listen to owl events:
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
   var list = document.getElementById("item");
   if(list.style.display = "none"){
     list.style.display = "block";
   }else{
     list.style.display = "none";
   }
})
```

is there anyway to make the chooses item to zoomed in ?

Comment: as you have one item why don't you try get this done by CSS. You can create a CSS rule to scale the image by .owl-item.active class.